# Is it possible to generate SAR like pictures with a non moving MIMO radar and static scene?

Tags: image-processing, radar, beamforming, mimo

Recently I study radar alot and was wondering if there is a possibility to generate SAR like pictures with MIMO radar.
Under the condition that the MIMO radar is not moving and the scene does not change.

I am curious about your ideas and papers if you have some.

Comment: This question for ideas is a bit too broad for the scope of this site. We kind of like precise questions that can have a "correct" answer :) So, I guess your question is "is this feasible?". Would I be right?

Comment: It depends. How big is your antenna? The whole idea of SAR is that you're achieving very good angular resolution by creating a large array over time instead of having an "instantaneous" array by virtue of having it built. If your array is small then the answer is no, but even that's relative to how good of an image you want to generate.

Answer (score 1):

I think we went through different educational paths when learning about SAR:

I learned

- how a single antenna works, and then
- how to create an antenna array and how to the antenna pattern arises from the array's geometry and the phase and amplitude of the signal sent to each element antenna, and then
- how you can define the pattern by using the antennas in a MIMO manner ("beamforming"), and then
- how you can emulate a large antenna array through means of Synthetic Aperture antennas (the SA in SAR!)

So, for me, SAR is just "emulated MIMO" (at a large size).

So, yes, it's the same thing; just that your MIMO antenna is probably very very small compared to the size of your synthetic aperture in SAR. Your *idea* is hence just the working principle underlying SAR to begin with.